# How to get Monday to Friday count using WEEKNUM?

Tags: powerbi, week-number

I need to get monday to friday count using WeekNum.This is the code im using but the values are not `visible.SysStartTime` and `new_sana_maldate` both should be from Monday to Friday.

```
MALS Lastweek = CALCULATE(
    COUNT(vw_sana_account[accountid]),
    FILTER(
    vw_sana_account,
    vw_sana_account[new_mal]= 1
    && vw_sana_account[SysStartTime] = WEEKNUM(vw_sana_account[new_sana_maldate].[Date],2 
)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count working days, give [this a look](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/counting-working-days-in-dax/).

Regarding your code, i can tell, that the

`&& vw_sana_account[SysStartTime] = WEEKNUM(vw_sana_account[new_sana_maldate].[Date],2 ))`

part is probably wrong,as you are applying weeknum function to only one of those, therefore comparing number with datetime. Try to add the weeknum function to the sysStartTime column as well

Comment: In that case iam not sure, where the issue might be, so if you can, please, provide sample data.

Comment: Also for debugging reasons, i would suggest you to create calculated columns containing weeknums for both columns and see, whether you are getting expected results

Comment: I have a calculated column for Last week using this code,   I have calculated column for the Last week using below code
LastWeek = 
VARCurrent_week= CALCULATE(MAX(DateTable[WeekOfYear]),
FILTER(DateTable,DateTable[Date].[Date]=TODAY()))
RETURN IF([DayOfWeek]= current_week,"Yes","No")

Comment: I really need the sample data to know more. The only thing that seems weird regarding the formula is the DateTable[Date].[Date], as you should not need .[Date] on the custom DateTable. Try to get rid of that